# Why $\frac{dy}{dx}=2\sqrt{y+1}\cos{x}$ with initial condition $y(\pi)=0$ has two solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved this differential equation and obtained two solutions, $y=(\sin(x)\pm 1)^2-1$, however I do not understand why the uniqueness part of Picard Lindelof's theorem does not apply if $\sqrt{y+1}$ is a Lipschitz function on $[0,\infty)$

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, *how* do you obtain two of them ? Aren't you trying to solve $y'=\color{red}\pm2\sqrt{y+1}\cos x$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you seem to be missing in verifying the proposed solutions is that in real analysis you always have $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$, and that $\sin x-1$ is always zero or negative.

If you got your solution formula from Wolfram Alpha, then you have to take into account that they use always the complex domain for greater generality. If your problem contains roots then this has the consequence that WA considers all the branches of the root in the complex domain as valid, so that additionally to the given equation WA also returns the solutions to $y'=-\sqrt{1+y}\cos x$. You have to filter out these spurious solutions or find the trick to tell WA to interpret the task only in the real domain.

---

As to your observations, you are correct, the right side is Lipschitz on, for instance, $y\in(-0.5,\infty)$, so that there can be no branching at points where $y=0$. And indeed,
$$
\frac{dy}{2\sqrt{1+y}}=\cos(x)dx\implies \sqrt{1+y}-\sqrt{1+0}=\sin(x)-\sin(\pi)
$$
gives only the function
$$
y(x)=(1+\sin x)^2-1
$$
as solution.

The branching can happen at values $y=-1$ where the term under the square root is zero. For this solution this value is taken at $x=\frac{3\pi}2,\frac{7\pi}2,...$ where you can switch with continuous derivative to the constant solution $y\equiv -1$ and from there after a time back to the non-constant solution.

Comment: But, for example, why is not $y=(\sin(x)-1)^2-1$ a solution if it satisfy the differential equation and intial point at $\pi$

Comment: @Almostnice : How does it satisfy the differential equation? $2(\sin x-1)\cos x = 2(1-\sin x)\cos x$ is not true after all.

Comment: If $y=(\sin(x)-1)^2-1$ then $y'=2\cos(x)(\sin(x)-1)$  and we also have $\sqrt{y+1}\cos(x)=\sqrt{(\sin(x)-1)^2}\cos(x)=(\sin(x)-1)\cos(x)$. And it satisfies $y(\pi)=0$ . I do not realize where I am wrong

Comment: You are wrong in that $\sin x\le 1$ always, so that $|\sin x-1|=1-\sin x$. Thus the sign difference of left and right side.

Answer (score 1):

Plugging

$$y=(\sin x\pm1)^2-1$$ in the equation, we get

$$2(\sin x\pm1)\cos x=2|\sin x\pm1|\cos x$$

or, after simplification

$$\sin x\pm1=|\sin x\pm1|.$$

As $\sin x-1\le0$, only the solution with a plus sign gives an identity.